# Capturing all items with arulessequences

Tags: r, arules

im in trouble with arulessequences. My date frame looks like

`Sequenz-ID Event-ID SIZE`

`1          1        2     A A`

`baskets <- read_baskets(con = "...filepath/test.txt", sep = "[ \t]+",info=c("sequenceID", "eventID", "SIZE"))`

but when i read it it looks like

`{A} 1 1 2`

however it fails to capture the items beyond the first column when it is the same one

for example if i read the data frame below

`Sequenz-ID Event-ID SIZE`

`1          1        2     A B`

it looks like this

`{A,B} 1 1 2`